# Hashing a Directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is there any command in linux to calculate SHA1 hash of a director which contains files + Directories(these directories future contains file and more directories).

Comment: This question looks off-topic. However you can use `sha1deep`. It is usually included in a package called `md5deep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to use this

```
find . -type f -exec sha1sum {} \;
```

Just replace the "." with your directory.

Answer (score 4):

```
tar cf - $DIRECTORY|sha1sum
```

Deficiencies/advantages (depending on your perspective):

- `$DIRECTORY` must be *exactly* the same in both cases (so you must use
  relative paths).
- This takes into account file modification dates, not just file contents.

Comment: Oh, that is much nicer

Comment: I like it... add a "p" and get ownership too!

Comment: In reality, if you were transferring a directory to another computer, you'd want to tar it first, then sha1sum it, then copy it (unless it was huge). Note that ssh (and hence sftp and scp) already provide good integrity checking.

Comment: @RobinGreen its a nice trick.. what do you mean by"$DIRECTORY must be exactly the same in both cases (so you must use relative paths)." I didn't understood it correctly?

Comment: If one directory is at `/home/user/foo` and another is at `/home/user/copy/foo` you can't use absolute paths when comparing them, because they will appear in the tar file, so the tar files will be different. (OK there is actually no tar file, I mean something like a "virtual tar file".) You can fix this by using a relative path such as `foo` or `.` in both cases. But of course you have to `cd` to the correct directory first.

Comment: @RobinGreen Thanks. One problem I am getting is: 
userme@test:/home$ sudo tar cf - myfolder|sha1sum;
tar: userme/.gvfs: Cannot stat: Permission denied
tar: userme/.cache/gnome-system-monitor.userme.658402558: socket ignored
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
734bac7e50e02756de91e98f2b57923a980cbfd6  -

Comment: @user3130920 try `sudo tar cf - myfolder|sha1sum`

Answer (score 0):

File by file you mean?

```
$ cd my_folder
$ sha1sum *
d73c8369c7808f7e96561b4c18d68233678f354f  xxx.txt
5941a4f547f69b4b6271a351242ce41b3e440795  yyy.txt
```

Or of all the files together?

```
$ cat my_folder/* | sha1sum 
7713154076812602f6f737cf5ad5924813182298
```